# How to make multiple table connections in symfony2 Repository ? Entity?

Tags: symfony, repository, entity

I have tables like 
`profile` `status`

Profile.class

```
id name
1  taro
2  jiro
3  john
```

Status.class

```
id profile school           date
1  1       highschool       2017-04-01
2  1       juniorhighschool 2013-04-01
3  2       highschool       2017-04-01
```

Status is added when status changes.

So I normally choose latest status every time I need status.

```
$ss = $this->em->createQuery(
  "SELECT cm FROM UserBundle:Status s where c.profile = :p order by desc")                 
                ->setParameters(['p' => $profile])->getResult();
$ss[0] // Latest Status
```

So now I would like to put this in function.

What I want to do is getting latest status from profile.

I have a few ideas

- Put this function in Profile Entity?
- put this function in Profile Repository?
- put this function in service???

In my opinion it should be the feature  of Profile Entity, So I would like to put this in Entity though, access another from an Entity is bad manner.

Is it OK to access another entity from a Profile Repository??

Or should I use service??

Comment: Perfectly acceptable for the Profile repository to return a status entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a method in ProfileRepository

```
<?php

public function getLastStatusByProfile(Profile $profile)
{
  // do our query from Profile with a join on Status
}
```

And please, use a LIMIT 1 on your query, you only need the last result

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put this in an Entity because Entities cannot be injected the Doctrine EntityManager dependency (`$this->em`).
To perform your "getLatestStatus()" function you need the EntityManager `$this->em`.

To access the EntityManager you can:

- get it from the container in a Command or a Controller (e.g. in a Controller `$this->get('doctrine')->getManager();`)
- inject it into a Service using Dependency Injection configuration files (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service)
- use it in a Repository because Repositories have native access to it

Usually people put functions such as `getLatestStatus()` in a repository, the repository becomes "the class where we put all DQL queries" and this works quite fine. This is recommanded by the official Documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html) "Methods containing your query logic can then be stored in this class."

It is usual in Symfony Applications to have:

- Entities having only properties, getters, setters, and some additionnal logical functions (like `activate()`, `disable()` ... functions that modify the Entity properties)
- Repositories to hold DQL queries with complex logic such as `getLatestStatus()`
- Services to hold other any other functions that read / modify data
- Controllers are only gateways to use Services

So one complete example would be:

```
<?php

class ProfileRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param Profile $profile 
     *
     * @return Status
     */
    public function getLatestStatus($profile)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        "SELECT cm FROM UserBundle:Status s where c.profile = :p order by desc")                 
                ->setParameters(['p' => $profile])
                ->getResult();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And do not forget to handle the case where there is no "status" available for this profile. Do you wish to return `null`, raise an Exception or return a default `status` ?